# Unable to access object properties while doing a post request

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, post

I am creating a post request that adds new posts to MongoDB. The post request works well and I can see the post in Mongo.

I am struggling at accessing properties from the object using `req.body`, specifically `req.body._id`. I would like to console.log the `req.body._id` to verify that it worked. In the terminal, I keep on getting 'undefined'.

All the solutions I have seen so far say include `app.use(express.json());` and `app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));` which I have.

I am stumped on what to try next. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Here is my server.js file

```
const express = require('express');
const dotenv = require("dotenv").config();
const mongoose = require('./db/mongoose');
const app = express();
const postsRoute = require('./routes/posts');

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use("/posts", postsRoute);

app.listen( process.env.PORT || 5000, (err) => {
    console.log(`listening on port ${process.env.PORT}`);
});
```

Here is my routes file

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const { allPosts, createPost } = require('../db/models/postModel');


router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
    console.log(`req.title is: ${req.title}`);
    try {
        const posts = await allPosts();
        res.send(posts);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err.message);
    }
    });

router.post("/create", async (req, res) => {
    const newPost = req.body;
    try {
        const addingPost = await createPost(newPost);
        console.log(`req.body is:${addingPost}`);
        console.log(`req.body title:${addingPost.title}`);
        console.log(`addingPost is: ${addingPost} with id of ${addingPost._id}`);
        res.send (addingPost);
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).send(err.message);
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

Here is my Schema file

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const postSchema = new Schema({
    author: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    content: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    tags: [String],
    file: String,
    likes: {
        type: Number,
        //We want to default to 0 likes
        default: 0,
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: new Date(),
    },
});


const postModel = mongoose.model('Post', postSchema);

//Get all posts
const allPosts = async () => {
    const posts = await postModel.find();
    return posts;
};

//Create posts
const createPost = async (post) => {
    const newPost = await postModel.create(post);
    return newPost;
};


module.exports = { allPosts, createPost };
```

[Console.log outputs in the Node REPL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcd9E.png)

I have included a picture showing what the console.log ouputs in the terminal. Hopefully this supports my question.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! `addingPost`, as it is returned by `postModel.create(newPost)` does _not_ have the same object properties as `newPost`. Try `addingPost.get("title")` and `addingPost.get("_id")`.

Comment: Thank you for you suggestion. I solved it. Turns out I had an unnecessary array in my ThunderClient post request. I took out the array and it works now.